# When is the composition of Markov kernels well-defined?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Wikipedia, and all resources I checked, seem to suggest that we can **always** compose two Markov kernels.

> Let $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$, $\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$, $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z})$ be measurable spaces and $K:\mathsf{X}\times\mathcal{Y} \to [0, 1]$ and $L:\mathsf{Y}\times\mathcal{Z}\to [0, 1]$ be two Markov kernels. Then the composition
> $$
>  (L\circ K)(x, \mathsf{A}) = \int_{\mathsf{Y}} L(y, \mathsf{A}) K(x, dy) \qquad\qquad \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{Z}, x\in\mathsf{X}
> > $$
> is a valid Markov kernel.

However, I feel that this requires a proof (which I have never found). Indeed the expression above is an **expectation** and hence does not always exist, necessarily. If we define the random variable $L_{\mathsf{A}}:\mathsf{Y}\to [0,1]$ then the new kernel is basically
$$
(L\circ K)(x, \mathsf{A}) \equiv \mathbb{E}[L_{\mathsf{A}}]
$$
As such, we should require the function $L_{\mathsf{A}}$ to be in the spaces
$$
L^p(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y}, K(x, \cdot); [0, 1]) := \left\{f:\mathsf{Y}\to[0, 1] \left| f \text{ is } \mathcal{Y}\text{-measurable and } \left(\int \|f(y)\|^p K(x, dy) \right)^{1/p} < \infty \right.\right\}
$$
for any $x\in\mathsf{X}$ and for any $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{Z}$, yypically, at least $p=1$.

Since the codomain is $([0, 1], \mathcal{B}([0, 1]))$ one can take $\|\cdot\|$ to be the absolute value. If we take the absolute value, as our norm for the Banach space, then since $L$ is always non-negative, this does not affect the integral. So really we are asking that
$$
\int_{\mathsf{Y}} L(y, \mathsf{A}) K(x, dy) < \infty
$$

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to show that the function $L(\cdot, \mathsf{A}):\mathsf{Y}\to [0, 1]$ is integrable for any $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{Z}$. One nice thing about this function is that it is bounded
$$
|L(y, \mathsf{A})| \leq 1 \qquad \qquad \forall\, y\in\mathsf{Y}, \forall \mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{Z}
$$

Comment: Maybe that fact, together with the fact that $K(x, \mathsf{Y}) = 1$, meaning that the whole space has finite measure. Maybe these two facts make $L$ integrable, but I don't know any such theory

Comment: Check out [Klenke](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Theory-Comprehensive-Course-Universitext/dp/144715360X) Ch. 14.2 , Th. 14.26 (warning: the author says *obvious*)

Comment: To be a Markov kernel $L(\cdot, A)$ is assumed to be measurable for every $A \mathcal{Z}$ and since it is bound by $1$ for every $A \in\mathcal{Z}$ it is integrable and even in $L^\infty\left(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y}, K(x, \cdot)\right)$ for all $x \in \mathsf{X}$.